# Filter orders that have a mismatch with order state with the last order state in order history

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop and I need to verify data integrity comparing the current state of each order with the last order history state registered.

The **orders** table:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦
║ id_order ║ current_state ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬
║    1     ║       3       ║ 
║    2     ║       1       ║
║    3     ║       2       ║
║    4     ║       1       ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩
```

The **order_history** table:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦
║ id_order_history ║ id_order ║ id_order_state ║      date_add       ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬
║        1         ║     1    ║       1        ║ 2016-08-01 11:00:00 ║
║        2         ║     2    ║       1        ║ 2016-08-02 12:00:00 ║
║        3         ║     1    ║       3        ║ 2016-08-03 13:00:00 ║
║        4         ║     3    ║       1        ║ 2016-08-04 14:00:00 ║
║        5         ║     3    ║       2        ║ 2016-08-05 15:00:00 ║
║        6         ║     2    ║       3        ║ 2016-08-06 16:00:00 ║
║        7         ║     4    ║       1        ║ 2016-08-07 17:00:00 ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩
```

(The voluntary missed table is to give a name for order states : 1 = "Paid", 2 = "Confirmed", 3 = "Shipped"…)

Normally, current_state order must be equal to the last state history entry, but sometimes not (in my sample, for order #2, current_state = 1 but the id_order_state of the last history update is 2), and thats what I want to reveal.

I do this to get the each last order state update:

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.current_state, h.id_order_state, max(h.date_add)
FROM orders o, order_history h
WHERE o.id_order = h.id_order
GROUP BY o.id_order, o.current_state, h.id_order_state
ORDER BY o.id_order ASC
```

But it's not enough because firstly I want only the states of the last update of each order:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id_order ║ current_state ║ id_order_state ║   max(h.date_add)   ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║    1     ║       3       ║       3        ║ 2016-08-03 13:00:00 ║
║    2     ║       1       ║       3        ║ 2016-08-06 16:00:00 ║
║    3     ║       2       ║       2        ║ 2016-08-05 15:00:00 ║
║    4     ║       1       ║       1        ║ 2016-08-07 17:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

And secondly add a filter with `WHERE current_state <> id_order_state` to show only corrupted data (like order #2):

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id_order ║ current_state ║ id_order_state ║   max(h.date_add)   ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║    2     ║       1       ║       3        ║ 2016-08-06 16:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Does a full SQL request can do this ?

Comment: I'm unclear what your question is.  You seem to want two very different things.

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm searching for the SQL request to give me the "secondly" output, but I mentioned the "firstly" to be the most precise in the process logic.

Comment: @sarcom: 1.6.0.14 but this does not seem significant here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT o.id_order
     , o.current_state
     , x.id_order_state
     , x.date_add
  FROM order_history x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id_order,MAX(date_add) date_add FROM order_history GROUP BY id_order ) y 
    ON y.id_order = x.id_order 
   AND y.date_add = x.date_add
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.id_order = x.id_order
 WHERE x.id_order_state <> o.current_state;
```

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry !! It works very well :) Only downside, subqueries seems not working inside Prestashop's 1.6.0.14 Admin Request SQL because this query give me a "checkedFrom" error. But I tested on PS 1.6.1.5 and it works well !

Answer (score 0):

Select the order history into a temporary table first by using the `max(h.date_add)` clause you already have.

You can then join to this using your query `WHERE o.id_order = h.id_order`

By putting it into a temporary table (or subquery) first, you have eliminated the problem of the multiple rows. You can then do the comparison on the order states which will tell you which ones are out of sync.

Think of it as pre-filtering the data you don't need from the history table first.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Klemart3D this is not a basic SQL query :)</strike> Sorry, I didn't see that the title was edited by another user :), however I guess (and I hope XD) that is the query that does what you need:

```
SELECT 
    o.`id_order`, o.`current_state`, h.`id_order_state`, h.`date_add`
FROM 
    `ps_order_history` h INNER JOIN (SELECT `id_order`, MAX(`date_add`) AS maxdateadd FROM `ps_order_history` GROUP BY id_order) laststatus ON (h.`id_order` = laststatus.`id_order` AND h.`date_add` = laststatus.`maxdateadd`)
    INNER JOIN `ps_orders` o ON (o.`id_order` = h.`id_order` AND o.`current_state` <> h.`id_order_state`)
ORDER BY h.`id_order` ASC
```

I have added the standard prefix `ps` to the tables name.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround, but some other queries posted here are better than mine:

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.current_state, h.id_order_state, h.date
FROM ps_orders o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_order, id_order_state, max(date_add) as date
    FROM ps_order_history
    GROUP BY id_order
    ORDER BY id_order DESC
) h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
WHERE o.current_state <> h.id_order_state 
GROUP BY o.id_order
ORDER BY o.id_order DESC
```

I have added the standard prefix `ps` to the tables name.

NB: This query don't works inside Prestashop's Request SQL (the subquery generates an "Undefined checkedFrom error" with PS v1.6.0.14).